# Can every function be represented as $ e^{kx} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Are all real continous elementary functions included in 
  $$ e^{kx} $$  $k$ is a complex number , $x$ is real variable . This question came to my mind when solving linear higher order ODE. We use a substitution like this to solve those equations and i often hear people say we assume the solution is a exponetial function, although we often get $  \sin, \cos $ functions ( which we get by the magic of euler formula).

If $k$  is a real number we have only the exponential function. If $k$ is equal to $i$ we get $  \sin, \cos $ can we get other all other functions such as $x^n$ or $\log x$ if $k$ is a complex number $a+ib$, then we would have
$$  e ^{(a+ib)x}=e^{ax}(\cos bx+i \sin bx)    $$

So can we find $a,b$ such this expression is equal to e.g. $ \sqrt x  $ for all $x$ . I think it is not possible but solving that equation for $a,b$ seems only possible numerically

Comment: Perhaps a simpler beginning would be to consider the function $x$...

Comment: How do you get $\log x$? You simply assert that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x=e^{\log{(x)}}$$
Now $\log{x}$ cannot be written as or even approximated by $kx$ for a constant $k$, so $x$ cannot be written in terms of $e^{kx}$.

Answer (score 2):

The constant function $f(x)=0$ is a counterexample as $\log0$ does not exist.

Comment: OP stated that $k$ can be complex valued

Comment: How about the zero function?

Comment: Yes this is a valid argument.